What happened to these Apace MINA artifacts in MINA major version 2?
I'm "modernizing" a legacy code base which used Apache MINA 1.x and I am trying to move it to MINA 2.2.4. The code base uses Maven for building. I managed to get a few dependencies moved to MINA 2.2.4 but are struggling to  understand what I need to do with the following artifacts:
mina-filter-ssl - is this one now integrated into mina-core and I do not need to list it in Maven dependencies anymore?
mina-filter-codec-netty - I could not find documentation on how to migrate this from 1.x to 2.x. In contrast, mina-integration-spring has been renamed to mina-integration-xbean according to their doc Changes Between 2.x and 1.x.
P.S. For those looking for how to fix dependency error for other artifacts such as mina-integration-jmx, OSGi is involved so maven-bundle-plugin with <extensions>true</extensions> must be used.
